# How can I encode a sets of numbers in a single memory word?

Tags: c

I found a post by optimusfrenk suggesting to encode a sets of numbers in a single memory word in order to get the intersection,he said: "For example, you could encode the set {0,2,3,6,7} in the memory word: ...00000011001101."; I can not find anything about this here and on the web.

How do I do that in c?

Thanks

Comment: [Bit manipulation in the C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Bit_manipulation_in_the_C_programming_language)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/694576

Comment: "*I can not find anything about this*" what **exactly** are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

> "[...] encode the set {0,2,3,6,7} in the memory word: ...00000011001101."

Bits

```
00000011001101
      ||  || |
      ||  || +- 0
      ||  |+--- 2
      ||  +---- 3
      |+------- 6
      +-------- 7
```

are set.

To set a bit use

```
value |= (1<<n);
```

to clear a bit

```
value &= ~(1<<n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a bit to any element in the set. And use bitwise arithmetic to compute derived sets.

Let's say that

```
elem_0 = 0b1;
elem_2 = 0b10;
elem_3 = 0b100;
elem_6 = 0b1000;
elem_7 = 0b10000;
```

Now, you can create a set by or-ing the elements.

```
set1 = elem_0 | elem_3;
set2 = elem_3 | elem_6 | elem_7;
```

now, you can compute intersection (and):

```
intersect = set1 & set2; // == 0x100 == elem_3
```

Or union (or):

```
union = set1 | set2; // == 0x11101 == elem_0 | elem_3 | elem_6 | elem_7
```

Complementary sets (negation)... and so on.

Comment: assigning bits with constants starting with `0x`?

Comment: Putting aside the wrong C syntax to express bit-values, your encoding scheme is different form the one presented by the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, the encoding is different just because I tried to generalize. You cannot encode 2018 with the shown schema. And you are right, this is not good C code. I was trying to be educative more than syntax-correct. I should had used pseudo-code.

Comment: Sure you could, as the meaning of the bits is a matter of definition. Just as your answer's definitions are different from the OP's definitions.

Comment: Well, I like both the answers, but in the second answer, make sense using values that are power of two to make sure that they are single bits, so: 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10 and so on